# Apache: mod_status stats differ from apachetop

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, monitoring

when comparing the output of `mod_status` and `apachetop`, there is about a 10 hits/sec difference.

- `mod_status` shows 2.91 hits/sec
- `apachetop` (given the apache access log) shows about 12 hits/sec

12 hits/sec is the right answer. why is `mod_status` showing a much lower value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mod_status give you the mean since the server startup while apachetop give mean since last 30 seconds by default (-T options)